# Why is this not sufficient to for adding a view to take up all the screen using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I cannot figure out why this is not working for adding a subview.

```
UIView *orangeView = [[UIView alloc] init];
orangeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
orangeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

[self.view addSubview:orangeView];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

I get no error or warning, but the view does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding constraints to `self.view` that make `self.view` the same dimensions as `self.view`. You never use `orangeView` when adding constraints.

Change your code to this:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:orangeView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```